# Full names with Chicago bibliographystyle

Tags: bibtex, natbib, chicago-style

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{chicago}` and the `Natbib` package. I would like to have the FULL NAMES of the authors listed in the bibliography. For instance:

`Lastname1, Name1, and Name2 Lastname2. 2013. My Paper Title. *My Journal Title* 1(1):1-25.`

Chicago is the style closest to my needs. Is there any way to tweak the original code to get the full Names.

Thanks a lot,

PS: Apologies if this question has been raised before. I could not find it myself.

Comment: [**`biblatex-chicago`**](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) does this by default.